# UITableViewCell returns null values when values are assigned using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a UITableViewController which should display all serviceName and Car Model. I have used subtitle as my UITableViewCell style. serviceName and Car Model are present in two different tables in Parse. I wrote the query and I am able to fetch the objectIDs of serviceName and Car model from the table. however when I try and use the objectIds to fetch the data from the respective tables I get a null value as return.

This is my currentjobs.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface currentJobs : UITableViewController{
    NSMutableArray *currentjobs;
    }
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *currentjobTable;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *servicerequestid;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *serviceid;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *carid;

@end
```

and this is my currentjobs.m file

```
#import "currentJobs.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface currentJobs ()

@end

@implementation currentJobs

@synthesize currentjobTable;
@synthesize servicerequestid;
@synthesize serviceid;
@synthesize carid;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *mechanicid = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;

    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ServiceStatus"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"mechanic" equalTo:mechanicid];
    [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *mechanicobjects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            currentjobs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:mechanicobjects];
            NSLog(@"%@", currentjobs);
        }
        [currentjobTable reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return currentjobs.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"currentjob" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    PFObject *mechanic = [currentjobs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    servicerequestid = [mechanic objectForKey:@"servicerequest"];
    NSLog(@"%@", servicerequestid);

    //query to find carid and serviceid
    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ServiceRequests"];
    [query2 getObjectInBackgroundWithId:servicerequestid block:^(PFObject *servicerequestobject, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){

            serviceid = [servicerequestobject objectForKey:@"serviceName"];
            carid = [servicerequestobject objectForKey:@"car"];


            NSLog(@"%@", serviceid);

            }
    }];

    //query to find servicename and display
   PFQuery *query3 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"services"];
    [query3 getObjectInBackgroundWithId:serviceid block:^(PFObject *serviceNameobject, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(@"objects Found");
            cell.textLabel.text = [serviceNameobject objectForKey:@"serviceName"];

        }
        else if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error Found");
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];

    //query to find car model and display
   PFQuery *query4 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"customerCars"];
    [query4 getObjectInBackgroundWithId:carid block:^(PFObject *customercarobject, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [customercarobject objectForKey:@"model"];
        }
    }];


    return cell;
}
@end
```

The query3 and query4 does seem to give me any kind of output. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem has to do with setting the delegate and datasource to self, as when you create a UITableViewController these values are set by default. But all you need to do to test that is throw break points in those methods when the table view loads. This could be an asynchronous issue, meaning you don't actually have the data at the time you're trying to use it. I recommended cleaning up your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I like to keep that method clean as what I'd do is actually use a DAO to hold my parse methods, or just have all those parse related calls in a method that can be called in the cellForRowAtIndexPath... Just looks better. Aside from that, I'm pretty sure this is an asynchronous issue, which is common when working with the numerous built in parse methods.

Comment: for testing purpose, I I tried to display the data on serviced on cell.textlabel and cared on cell.detailtext and they are getting displayed correctly. The query3 and query4 does not seem to do anything here.

Comment: Then two things could possibly be the problem here. First check and make sure all your query keys and class names and all that stuff is identical to what your parse server shows. I believe it is case sensitive, so check that and spell everything right. The problem which I really think it is.. Is just an asynchronous issue. It's really easy to debug and check if you're getting any data at all. And if you are getting the data, then you are not using it or adding it to your array at the correct time.

Comment: Btw in query1 make sure that key "mechanic" Is actually equal to mechanicid. That is very important

Comment: I made the necessary changed as pointed. I made a function for the queries and calling them when loading the cell. Now the problem is implement displaying of cell first then going to the the called function. Hence display is again null. I printed the data in the function and they are printing fine. :( any suggestions

Comment: You're missing the biggest thing that i repeatedly keep bringing up which is ASYNCHRONOUS programming. I highly recommend you look into it and understand it. You should be a taking a more object oriented approach here by making a class. I will post an example

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you are implementing UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate protocols. I don't see either that you set your CurrentJobs class as the delegate and datasource of your tableview. Without doing that, non of your UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource methods will be called in your CurrentJobs class.

Comment: The datasource and delegate are implemented by default. do not have to call implement them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Image : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage  *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageId;

@end

#import "Image.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface TableViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString       *imageId;

@end

@implementation TableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   [self fetchAllImages];
}

    #pragma mark Retrieve All Images from Parse Server
    -(void)fetchAllImages {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"imagePost"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            for(PFObject *tempParseObject in objects){
                NSString *imageName       = tempParseObject[@"name"];
                PFFile   *imageFile       = tempParseObject[@"image"];
                NSString *imageId         = tempParseObject.objectId ;
                UIImage *image            = [UIImage imageWithData:imageFile.getData];
                Image *retrievedImage   = [[Image alloc] init];
                retrievedImage.image    = image;
                retrievedImage.name     = imageName;
                retrievedImage.imageId  = imageId;
                [self.array addObject:retrievedImage];
            }
        }];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return  self.array.count;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        if(!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        }
        Image *retrievedImage = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image  = retrievedImage.image;
        cell.textLabel.text   = retrievedImage.name;
        self.imageID          = retrievedImage.imageId;

        return cell;
    }

@end
```

So as a quick side note.. this is not a good way to retrieve an Image/PFFile from parse as it will cause a long running operation in the main thread but its purpose here will serve as a simple example for how you should structure your code here. I query classname and retrieve the image, name and objectId, which happens when the view loads. I store them in temporary variables. Then i initialize my custom Image class, and assign its properties to the temporary variables. I then add that Image object to my array. This array is then used for the table view delegate and datasource methods. finally i create another Image variable and assign it to my array at indexpath.row and set the TEXT and IMAGE values of the UITableViewCell there.

The imageId is used if needed. I don't support naming conventions like naming an NSMutableArray as 'array', however, it should be a property over a plain ivar, though it technically won't make a difference in this case. Hope this simple example helps

Comment: I figured out how to execute the methods. I made the function calls as synchronous instead of Asynchronous calls by removing in the background from the parse queries.

Comment: That's probably not recommended at all but may work just fine for your smaller scale app.